# How can I install both mod-perl2 and mod-php5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mod-perl, mod-php

From Ubuntu's package libary, I find the two modules I need. However:

- mod-perl2 requires apache2-mpm-worker
- mod-php5 requires apache2-mpm-prefork

The two apache modules are mutually exclusive and ask me to un-install the other in order to install each. Which means I can't get a server running with both mod-perl2 and mod-php5.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package listings ([here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libapache2-mod-php5) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libapache2-mod-perl2)) both should work with mpm-perfork.
Does the package managemer complain if you try
`aptitude install apache2-mpm-perfork libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache2-mod-php5`
? If so, it would be worth adding the output from that command to your question.

There is also the less standard apache2-mpm-itk (package described [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/apache2-mpm-itk)) which both those pages list as being supported Apache setups, though as this is less common if mpm-perfork works that would be more recommended.

Comment: Thanks David. I had just discovered that both could use prefork and it was all about the order in which I was doing things. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that it's all about the order in which you do things.

I had installed mod-perl2, which required apache2-mpm-worker (which uses threads).

I then tried to install mod-php5. mod-php5 can't use threads and so needed me to uninstall apache2-mpm-worker and install apache2-mpm-prefork. Which in turn needed to uninstall mod-perl5 as it depended on it.

However, mod-perl2 doesn't actually require 'worker'. It can use 'prefork' if it needs to. It just prefers worker.

So if anyone comes along and needs to get both installed:

1. Install mod-php5 and let it install apache2-mpm-prefork
2. Install mod-perl2 and it will be happy

If you do it around the other way, you'll thing (as I did) that you can't install both on the same system via the package manager.